# Python: Sharing objects across modules & shell

Tags: python, oop, architecture

Long time listener, first time caller.

I have a high level design question, which may be overly general but here goes:
Currently, I have written a decently-sized set of modules. I use them by writing long scripts that call the modules. I need to refactor to make this more interactive; rather than relying on long scripts, want to call functions and modify object instances from the shell.

Problem: Need to share object instances across all the modules and with the shell.

Currently, just made a module that contains the object instance initializations, and all other modules import shared instances from this "workspace" module. I figure there must be a more elegant way to do this; any suggestions?

P.S. Originally, used object methods, but after talking with an actual programmer (I'm a mechanical guy), he advised me to only use objects as containers for attributes, and to break out the methods separately.

**Edit:** Changed the example code to include multiple instances & remove extraneous folders/files.

**Note:** The object method vs. separate method question is interesting, but the main question here is access to instances from modules and from the shell.

---

Attempt at a trivial generalized example:

(Disclaimer: this is nonsense code, just trying to show in general the type of issue I am trying to solve. i.e. modifying object instances both by calling methods and by directly altering attributes from the shell.)

```
===== folder structure =====

dev/init.py
dev/bike.py
dev/car.py
dev/workspace.py

===== init.py ======

from workspace import *
import bike
import car

===== workspace.py =====

class Bike:
    pass

class Car:
    pass

b = [Bike(), Bike()]
c = Car()

===== bike.py =====

from workspace import *

def start():
   b[0].x = 6
   b[1].x = 9

def move():
   b[0].x += 1
   b[1].x += 1.2

def distance():
    print(b[0].x-c.x)

===== car.py =====

from workspace import *

def start():
   c.x = 0

def move():
   c.x += 2

def brake(bike_instance):
    if bike_instance.x - c.x < 2:
        c.x = 0
```

Example usage:

```
$ python init.py -i
>>> bike.start()
>>> car.start()
>>> bike.move()
>>> car.move()
>>> car.move()
>>> car.move()
>>> bike.distance()
>>> car.brake(b[0])
>>> car.brake(b[1])
>>> c.x = 5
```

Comment: maybe it is something you could tackle with pickle? I.e. add a wrapper / decorator such that you load and unpickle an object when entering a function and you re-pickle and store it again on exit? (same for methods)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I'm curious: what does your programmer friend have against having relevant methods inside their corresponding class? If it makes sense for a function to be a class method, then you should absolutely do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically only want there to be a single instance of each class in each module? You never want two cars?

Comment: I agree with @kuyan. Your friend gave you horrible advice. I'm guessing that he's a C programmer who uses structs for holding related data, and writes functions to act on those structs. Nothing wrong with that within its context, but it's a terrible mismatch with Python's idioms.

Comment: Programmer friend told me that it would help maintain compatibility as I add to the code. I pickle the "bikes" and may want to use them weeks or months in the future when the code has changed considerably. It did feel like strange advice, code was cleaner with the methods inside the classes. 

To do multiple instances, used a list of "bikes" in the workspace instead of a single instance.

Comment: have you tried [ipython notebooks](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/htmlnotebook.html)?

Comment: @KirkStrauser: there is nothing wrong (or unpythonic) in keeping application logic separate from the way the data is stored. Some people prefer to keep their Model (as in ORM) classes dumb (to contain only data attributes or a very stable fixed set of methods (as in REST)).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But then, I wouldn't put application logic in classes. I'd put object logic there. For instance, I wouldn't write a `print_object` function that has code like `if isinstance(obj, MyClass1): dosomething(obj)`, `if isinstance(obj, MyClass2): somethingelse(obj)`.

Comment: @KirkStrauser: I see no connection between what I wrote and your last comment (all that non-sense with `isinstance()`).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I regret that you wrote off my honest attempts at discussion as nonsense, and politely withdraw from the conversation. Best wishes on a happy and productive week.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your expected workflow is, or what is in your `init.py` at the root of the package, but I would think your modules should each define their classes. And then you would create instances of those classes in your entry point and use them. What you are doing right now, creating instances is a side-effect of the import, as a "Singleton"-type pattern. What if you want 2 bikes or 2 cars?

*dev/modules/car.py*

```
class Car:
    pass
```

*dev/modules/bike.py*

```
class Bike:
    pass
```

*dev/init.py* (or workspace, as I don't know what it is really for)

```
from modules import bike, car

aBike = bike.Bike()
aCar = car.Car()
```

Comment: Heya; problem then is how to access aBike from within aCar and vice versa... do wind up creating multiple "bikes" or "cars".

Comment: They should not be depending on each other. That would imply a circular import which is not good design. A bike module should define bikes. A car module defines cars. You import them into a scripts to use them.

Comment: Looked up "Singleton" patterns, that does indeed seem to be what the "workspace.py" module does. I changed the example to show how I'm accommodating multiple bikes (workspace defines list rather than single instance). I see that circular import is bad; would you recommend anything other than passing instances as arguments every time, i.e. 'car.brake(b)'?

Comment: If one object is supposed to operate on another object, then passing it as an argument seems to be appropriate to me. Otherwise, if you know a car regularly needs to operate on a bike, then you could store the bike on the car as a member, and have all of your methods use it internally:  `aCar.setBike(aBike); aCar.brake(); aCar.distanceTo()`, though I think if you want it to operate on any number of bikes, it should still be an arg you pass.